# Error when trying to ng add @nativescript/schematics to existing angular project

Tags: angular, nativescript

I have an existing Angular 8 project where I tried to add nativescript. However when running the `ng add @nativescript/schematics` like it says in the documentation, I get this error: `Failed to find generated component file /auto-generated.component.css. Please contact the @nativescript/schematics author.`

Does anyone know what causes this error or what I could do to solve it?
As a reference, I tried to follow these steps https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/migrating-a-web-project

Comment: Did you check the related [Github issue](https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-schematics/issues/238), looks like SCSS is not supported yet.